# Sum two rows in Excel based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel

I'd like to sum the lpqty and receivedqty columns for every two rows in Excel, and I'm struggling to find a way to do it. I want a list of the first 4 columns, where the week values only appear once, not twice as it is right now. (Ignore the iog column). So essentially I want it to look something like this:

- 2018 9 35 BCN1 59380 109963

  2018 9 36 BCN1 356071 724178

[image]

I've tried with some SUM and OFFSET formulas, but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

For the first 4 columns:

```
=INDEX(A:A,(ROW()*2-2))
```

starting in (say) J2

Then for the next 2 columns:

```
=INDEX(F:F,(ROW()*2-2))+INDEX(F:F,(ROW()*2-1))
```

(assumes all rows are strictly in pairs)

[image]